# IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN')

Tags: queue, connection, jms, ibm-mq, mq

I'm getting this error till there was no publisher to the topic. As soon as there was a publisher and the message started to get published on the topic, the JMS listener was actively listening and the error message was gone.

And sometimes it doesn't throw error for a month, then suddenly it throws 1-2 error messages and starts working again.

Do you have any suggestions?

Related dependencies;

```
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>3.1.3</spring.boot.version>
        <springframework.version>6.0.11</springframework.version>

        <jakarta.annotation.version>2.1.1</jakarta.annotation.version>
        <jakarta.xml.version>4.0.0</jakarta.xml.version>
        <jakarta.xml.soap.version>3.0.0</jakarta.xml.soap.version>
        <jakarta.jws.version>3.0.0</jakarta.jws.version>
        <jakarta.jms.version>3.1.0</jakarta.jms.version>
        <jakarta.servlet.version>6.0.0</jakarta.servlet.version>
        <jakarta.mail.version>1.1.0</jakarta.mail.version>
        <ibm.mq.jakarta.version>9.3.3.0</ibm.mq.jakarta.version>

        <tomcat.annotations.version>10.1.12</tomcat.annotations.version>
        <tomcat.version>11.0.0-M4</tomcat.version>
```

```
   Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
An error has occurred with the IBM MQ JMS connection.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
                         Class : class com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedJMSException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:829)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.close(WMQSession.java:783)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:632)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:355)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQSession.close(MQSession.java:280)
                               : org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeSession(JmsUtils.java:109)
                               : org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1289)
                               : org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1135)
                               : java.lang.Thread.run(null:-1)


     Caused by [1] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.MQException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:829)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.close(WMQSession.java:783)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:632)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:355)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQSession.close(MQSession.java:280)
                               : org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeSession(JmsUtils.java:109)
                               : org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1289)
                               : org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1135)
                               : java.lang.Thread.run(null:-1)


     Caused by [2] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9206: Error sending data to host '{HOST} {HOST}'. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2009],3={HOST} {HOST}),4=TCP,5=RemoteTCPConnection.send(byte [ ],int,int,int,int)]
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException
                         Stack : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.send(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1830)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.wrapSend(RemoteConnection.java:3027)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.sendTSH(RemoteConnection.java:2793)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.sendTSH(RemoteSession.java:793)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.sendTSH(RemoteSession.java:709)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQDISC(RemoteFAP.java:1678)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQDISC(RemoteFAP.java:1613)
                               : com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.MQDISC(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:410)
                               : com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.MQDISC(ESEJMQI.java:396)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:817)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.close(WMQSession.java:783)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:632)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:355)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQSession.close(MQSession.java:280)
                               : org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeSession(JmsUtils.java:109)
                               : org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1289)
                               : org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1135)
                               : java.lang.Thread.run(null:-1)


     Caused by [3] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException
                         Stack : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.asyncConnectionBroken(RemoteConnection.java:3891)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:644)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1240)
     Caused by [4] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host '{HOST} {HOST})'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=k{HOST} {HOST},4=TCP]
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException
                         Stack : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveBuffer(RemoteRcvThread.java:858)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:798)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:161)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1240)
'.

EXPLANATION:
An attempt was made to deliver an exception to the connections exception listener but a listener has not been registered.

ACTION:
An exception listener must be registered with the connection to receive its exceptions.
```

I tried to change version of ibmmq and some other dependencies.
Also firstly I had the error when Im using javax dependecies and Im totally migrated to jakarta. But still I have same error.

Comment: MQRC 2009 - means the connection to queue manager was broken. This could be due to multiple reasons - a network blip, queue manager stopped or went down or server connection channel was stopped. You will need to investigate these possibilities.

Comment: For what it's worth, the "dependencies" you enumerated here are not dependencies at all. They just look like Maven properties with version numbers. There's no clear indication of the actual Maven coordinates for the dependencies you're using.

Comment: I agree with Shashi this could be due to multiple reasons. However, that this does not occur when Publishers send something might indicate that it is this traffic which keeps the connection active. Do you have a firewall between your application and MQ? They usually drop a session if there has not been any traffic for a configurable amount of time. If you can confirm this, you can prevent those Firewall timeouts by defining Keepalive either on on MQ level, or on TCP level (config change on OS parms and MQ) or both.

Comment: You can also prevent it by setting the HBINT of the SVRCONN to something lower than the firewall timeout, this also has the added benefit of allowing the channel to notice an issue with the connection sooner.

Comment: Probably you are right @NineFriends , because I have firewall between app and MQ. I will check that thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Did the firewall fixes as suggested by @NineFriends and JoshMc fix the connection broken issue?

Comment: Yes that worked @chughts

Comment: Please convert the salient parts of the comments into an answer and mark this question closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a firewall between my application and MQ. And it was dropping a session if there has not been any traffic for a configurable amount of time. On mq level I define keepAlive. Problem solved.